# Crontab not working on Mac

Tags: python, macos, cron

I've been trying to set up a cron job on my Mac in terminal to run a Twitter python script, but have had no luck. Running the script manually works every time, but automating the process with a crontab does not.

checking the status of the cron job by typing "crontab -l" reveals the following:

```
50 * * * * python /Downloads/Pat-Autofollow-API/sample_twitter_codes.py
```

However, the cron job does not run. I've tried playing around with the time variables to no avail, and still have not figured it out.

Comment: Put the `full` path to `python` and to your script.

Comment: Sorry Mark, my knowledge of coding is very limited. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In Terminal, type `which python` and whatever it says, put that in crontab in place of your plain `python` - it'll be something like `/usr/bin/python`.... second edit to follow..

Comment: Find where `/Downloads/Pat....` really is in the Finder, and put that in your crontab, it'll probably be somewhere like `/Users/FreddyFrog/Downloads/Pat....`

Answer (score 0):

A simple and elegant solution to this is to always include `#!/usr/local/env python` at the top of your python scripts.

```
#!/usr/local/env python

def thingy(n):
    pass
```

The shell interprets this as the environment which you would like this to be executed in. That way you don't have to always put the path to Python when specifying a cronjob, you can just point to the script.